# Export to SVG with Polygon IDs

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, svg

So `v.out.svg` works perfectly fine for my purpose, except that it doesn't export polygon IDs, so I have no way to identify them in the output. I want to use one of the attributes (specifically the **Name** attribute) as the ID of each polygon.

This dialog even allows me to specify "Attribute(s) to include in output SVG", but selecting my attribute in this option doesn't change the output in any way.

I need the attribute to be in SVG content (as an XML attribute of the corresponding  element.

Is there another way of doing what I'm after?

[image]

Comment: You could use Split vector layer tool to split the layer by an attribute. Then export each layer as svg with the attribute in the file name.

Comment: @csk: I used split and created 160 shape files. How do I export them to a single SVG now, with the file name in attribute?

Comment: The shapefiles created by the split vector layer tool should have the attribute in their file name. So export each shapefile as an svg with the same file name.

Comment: @csk: They do, but I need that attribute to be in SVG content (as an XML attribute of the corresponding `<path>` element). Are you suggesting that I manually copy them?

Comment: No, I was suggesting that you preserve the attribute values as field names instead of as XML attributes, because I misunderstood what you were asking for. Sorry to lead you down the wrong path.